# Javascript - Limit td:nth-child to max columns [1-3]

Tags: javascript

Hello  i have A table inside a table like that :

```
<table id="t4">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td> //Here Another Table </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

To render a chart i use in javascript this code to get data

```
  var obj, table = $("#t4"), array = [];
   table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
   var rows = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + columnOrder +')');
   rows.each(function(){
    obj = {};
    obj[keyName] = $(this).text();
    array.push(obj);
    });
    });
    return array;
    }
```

The problem is, this line is going to get data also from the table inside my table.

I would like to limit that javascript code to the outside table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector to only select the rows and cells of direct children

```
table.find('> tbody > tr')
```

and

```
.find('> td...
```